# Missing characters on taskbar

Tags: gnome-shell, taskbar

Taskbar on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS is missing characters on the clock and activities section. No idea what caused it and first I've seen it. Is there a way to fix/restart it without a reboot?

[image: taskbar]

Extensins as requested:

Apr  2 11:12 caffeine@patapon.info
Apr  2 11:12 emoji-selector@maestroschan.fr

Comment: You've either themed your account, or installed an incompatible GNOME extension. Either set the theme back to a supplied theme, and/or temporarily disable all GNOME extensions, restart GNOME shell, and see if that cures the problem. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back.

Comment: Updated. Definitely didn't do anything to explicitly theme it.

Comment: Temporarily disable emoji-selector, restart GNOME shell, and retest. Report back.

Comment: Unfortunately it came back on its own, maybe after device sleeping, so I can't replicate. Will try this if it happens again.

Comment: Best to temporarily disable the extension now, and see if the problem returns. Otherwise you won't have eliminated anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can restart GNOME shell without a reboot by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then typing `r`, and finally pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This should reload the top-bar too.

Comment: Thanks. Was curious if there's a way to avoid restarting GNOME shell, ie just reload the top bar, but maybe not possible.